# What is the convention for changing ownership of an std::unique_ptr via member call?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, stl, unique-ptr

When passing an `std::unique_ptr` by value (or an rvalue reference) the user is explicitly forced to call `std::move` (or cast to rvalue) thus resulting in greater clarity.  However when one is passed by lvalue reference the method being called can simply call `std::move` itself, also transferring ownership, but with shorter user code. So, the question is:

When an object takes ownership of an object via an `std::unique_ptr`, is the convention to pass it by value, rvalue reference or lvalue reference?

Comment: You can pass by lvalue reference for something like a repeated trial-and-error scheme, where you ask, "will you take my pointer?", and then you can check the result by looking at what's left behind.